# How do I replace strings with ID's using VBA?

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

I searched for an answer to this question, but it seems like the only ways that people have answered it are using Excel functions.  I have a file in Excel that I load in to a text file, but new data comes out every week.  I need to replace the Market names in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1PUH.png) first column with their respective tickers, which are in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRLAs.png) separate worksheet, but in the same Excel file.

For example, I want all 'CANADIAN DOLLAR - CHICAGO MERCANTILE EXCHANGE' cells to be replaced with 'CAD', all 'SWISS FRANC - CHICAGO MERCANTILE EXCHANGE' cells to be replaced with 'SWF', etc.

I would prefer if the names remained the same in the Excel file and were only changed when I transferred them to the text file.  However, that's not essential if it's harder to do.

For reference, here's the code I'm using to write to the text file:

```
Sub getData1()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
''Finding Row Information
Dim Ticker As String
Dim rCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, rcCount As Integer, rowStr As String
rCount = Application.CountA([RDRows])
rcCount = Application.CountA([RDCols])
Myfile = "H:\wkoorbusch\Desktop\" & "CFTC_Fin_Data.txt"

Dim fnum As Integer
fnum = FreeFile
Open Myfile For Output As fnum
For i = 1 To rCount
    For j = 1 To rcCount
        rowStr = [Start].Offset(i, 0).Value & "," & [Start].Offset(0, j).Value _
        & "," & Format([Start].Offset(i, 2).Value, _
        "mm/dd/yyyy") & "," & [Start].Offset(i, j).Value
        Print #fnum, rowStr
    Next j
Next i
Close fnum
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Close fnum
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Two things. 1) Why are you using a loop to write to the text file? Excel can `SaveAs` a text file. All you need to do is set the data in the relevant format in a new sheet and then save that sheet directly as a text file. That will be very fast. 2) You can either use `Vlookup` from VBA or use `.FIND` and `.FINDNEXT` in lieu of `Vlookup` to find and replace those words. See this link SECTION 4 http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: The reason I'm not using 'SaveAs' is because I'm reformatting the data as it comes out, with each one piece of data as its own row instead of huge rows that contain every bit of data for a single date+index combination.  These text files are then being written to our database in this format using SQL.

Comment: Fair Enough :) Did you see the 2nd point?

Comment: I did.  However, I'm still having trouble actually using those functions as I'm pretty new to VBA still.

Comment: `I'm still having trouble actually using those functions as I'm pretty new to VBA still.` Then I guess this is the right time to learn more about VBA by experimenting :) Here is the Logic 1) Before you write to the Text file, Loop through each row in `Ticker Symbols` Sheet and replace all the values in `RAW DATA` sheet using `.FIND` and `REPLACE ALL` 2) Once you are done, close the Excel file without saving. This will ensure that your original data remains unedited. 3) You also might want to record a macro and see how it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Text and its replacement in 2 colums of your spreadsheet, then use

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MyText,range("Sheet1!A1:B300"),2,False)
If Err.Number=1004 then msgbox "Value " & MyText & " not found"
```

to return the replacement text.
A trappable err.Number of 1004 is returned when the lookup value is not found.

(functionally equivalent to `VLOOKUP` as a spreadsheet formula)